# Как отформатировать текст, отображаемый через функцию валидации Yii2?

Tags: html, css, yii2

В файле Yii2 `RequiredValidator.php` с помощью приведенной ниже функции на страницу выводится предупреждение. Как изменить размер, цвет, написание шрифта предупреждения, если html-теги внутри функции не работают?

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    if ($this->message === null) {
        $this->message = $this->requiredValue === null ? Yii::t('yii', 'Поле "{attribute}" не может быть пустым')
            : Yii::t('yii', '{attribute} must be "{requiredValue}".');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавляешь теги в текст

```
 $message => "бла бла бла <span class='youClassCss'>Бла бла</span>"
```

В форме

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'email', ['errorOptions' => ['class' => 'help-block' ,'encode' => false]])->textInput() ?>
```

2ой вариант:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'email', [
'template' => "{label}\n{hint}\n{input}\n<span class='youClassCss'> {error}</span>"
])->textInput() ?>
```

Comment: не могу пока никак прокомментировать ответ - придется соображать куда это все приткнуть. если поясните получится, видимо, быстрее. в Yii только начинаю разбираться

Comment: Ты валидируешь какието входные данные (например login). В модели пишешь [['login'], 'required']. В форме откуда принимаешь данные, выводишь input'ы таким образом <?= $form->field($model, 'login', ['errorOptions' => ['class' => 'help-block' ,'encode' => false]])->textInput() ?> ну или вторым образом как я написал выше

Comment: 1. проблема в том, что теги внутри переменной $message не срабатывают как теги, а прописываются как html-текст.  
2. правильно понял, что во второй строке кода опечатка и вместо 'help-block' должно быть 'youClassCss'? 
3. у меня в проекте не наблюдается переменной {hint} и класса 'help-block' - их можно просто вычесть?

Comment: Ты message менял в RequiredValidator.php? Тебе туда лезть ВООБЩЕ не надо (Только переопределяешь классы, не меняешь базовые!!!!).  2. правильно понял - правильно. ставиш свой класс, а лучше добавь второй свой youClassCss. 3. {hint} - Это часть шаблона вывода полей ввода (по умолчанию из базового класса. Ты можешь их переопределить). Выглядеть будет так: <?= $form->field($model, 'login', ['errorOptions' => ['class' => 'help-block youClassCss']])->textInput() ?>. Я у себя проверил, стили меняются

Comment: 1. куда тогда надо?

Comment: Тебе нужно изменить текст или изменить стиль?

Comment: Следуя твоему вопросу. У тебя есть форма на которой ты проверяешь введённые данные на пустоту. Если поле пустое, то выводит сообщение из RequiredValidator.php с текстом Поле "{attribute}" не может быть пустым. Тебе нужно изменить размер, шрифт цвет. Поля этой формы выводятся <?= $form->field($model, 'login'])->textInput() ?> Тебе нужно заменить на <?= $form->field($model, 'название поля', ['errorOptions' => ['class' => 'help-block youClassCss']])->textInput() ?> И теперь в файле стилей, например css/style.css, добавить стиль youClassCss и назначить ему размер, цвет и шрифт

Comment: и текст и стиль. В файле _form.php из подпапки 'views' сделал так: 

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('Имя <span class="note">* поле обязательно к заполнению</span>') ?> 
есть соображения насколько это правильно относительно твоего варианта?

Comment: ага. похоже сам нашел близкий способ. спасибо

Comment: Чтобы изменить текст идёшь в модель твоей формы. Там находишь поле, например [['login'], 'requared'] и меняешь на [['login'], 'requared', 'message' => 'твое сообщение']

Comment: ->label('имя') это ты меняешь название поля, а не сообщение

Comment: ты прав - работает и через "модель твоей формы" (с) так лучше - согласен.
Насчет изменения названия поля вместо сообщения все верно - спутал части задачки. это был другой ее пункт, не заявленный мной раньше